# How to combine simultaneously the fragile- and the label-command for a frame?

Tags: beamer, verbatim, labels

I am currently facing the following problem in the beamer-class for LaTeX: I would like to label a frame and simultaneously use a verbatim-environment. Most likely the solution is very easy but I do not figure out how to address this issue correctly. Next you find a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=supplemental][fragile]
\begin{verbbox}
TEXT
\end{verbbox}
\resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{\theverbbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the pdf-output displays the "[fragile]"-element, too. However, if I simply combine both commands in one single bracket, i.e., the label- and the fragile-command, I get an error-message.
If I delete either the first or the second []-command the results are not as I want them.

How can I fix this? Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! One single bracket is the way to go, if any. What was the syntax you tried with one single bracket (order of the parameters, separator...), and what was the error message?

Comment: Is `[label=supplemental,fragile]` what you want?

Comment: That was my first idea, too. Unfortunately, I get an error using one single bracket for both alternatives:
    `[fragile,label=supplemental]`
    `[label=supplemental,fragile]`
The error is as follows:
`! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> presentation_TEST_2.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}`

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Are you compiling exactly the code as copy-pasted from the question (except for the modification for a single group of brackets)?

Comment: Yes, I am running exactly the code above. But neither with the MWE nor with my full presentation it is working. Actually, I do only get NO error message if I use the code above even though the result is not satisfying.

Comment: How is it not satisfying?

Comment: As described above: using two brackets the [fragile]-command is displayed in the pdf-output, too. Further, two slides are used. However, I only would like to have displayed the elements of the verbatim-environment.

Comment: @Sigur : May I ask you if you have tried to reproduce the code above? If yes, what was your result?

Comment: I have, I just changed the inner `][` for a comma, so that I get a single group of braces. The result is no error, and output is as expected as far as I can tell. What version of `beamer` and `verbatimbox` are you using?

Comment: @Phil, yes. As T. Verron said, no errors and the result was the desired one.

Comment: That's interesting!! I am using for the package `verbatimbox` 2013/04/24 v3.0 and for `beamer` 2013/01/04 3.26. Are these outdated?

Comment: They are slightly outdated, yes: my `TeXLive 2013` installation has `verbatimbox` last updated on march 2014, and `beamer` on december 2013. That does not necessarily mean that it is the cause of your issue, but you can still try and upgrade your distribution.

Comment: Before upgrading your distribution, you can also try to delete the auxiliary files created by `LaTex`, especially the `.vrb` file(s) created by `beamer` with `fragile`, and the `.aux` file setting the `label`.

Comment: I have just seen that the Tex Live distribution was updated few days ago. I assume that updating the entire distribution will also fix the problems of the up-to-date problems of `beamer` and `verbatimbox`. Is that right?

Comment: Ok, it's getting really strange: I updated my entire distribution (now Tex Live 2014, i.e., the versions used for `verbatimbox` and `beamer` are the most recent ones) and I also deleted `.aux` and `.vrb` files but I still get the same error message as before. What might be the problem?!

Comment: One last update: now it is working, not with the MWE, but luckily with the entire presentation. Before the update of the distribution it was not working with neither the former nor the latter. Consequently, something in the MWE might be wrong, but on the other hand for you it was working... I am thankful for your help, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The original problem was solved in comments, I'm only posting this to make the corrected MWE available somewhere in the page)

Only one group of braces should be used, `beamer`'s `frame` uses keyval options, not optional parameters in the usual sense.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=supplemental,fragile]
 \begin{verbbox}
  Verbatim : % $ #
 \end{verbbox}
 \resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{\theverbbox}
\end{frame}

\againframe{supplemental}

\end{document}
```